# convert a nagios config file to csv

Tags: bash, powershell, nagios

I have a Nagios directory which contains some servers config files :

```
define host {
   host_name            server1.srv
   hostgroups           linux-servers+holmes
   check_interval           5
}

define host {
   host_name            server2.srv
   hostgroups           linux-servers+holmes
   check_interval           5
}
```

I would like to reformat that data into CSV so I would get :

```
host_name,hostgroups,check_interval
server1.srv,linux-servers+holmes,5
server2.srv,linux-servers+holmes,5
```

I am happy to do this with either bash or powershell but I am not enough of a scripting guru to know how to do this...If anyone has a suggestion that would be greatly appreciated :) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This awk should work :

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "host_name,hostgroups,check_interval"} /host_name/{v1=$2} /hostgroups/{v2=$2} /check_interval/{v3=$2} /}/{print v1","v2","v3; v1=v2=v3=""}' file
```

Comment: Svante you're a legend ! Works like a charm :D Thanks very much mate :)

Comment: Just one little comment to add to this. If the line hostgroups or check_interval is missing from define host{} then that command will use the last values of $2 which is not correct. 

Would you be able to tell me how to get this sorted ?

Thanks very much !

Comment: Yes, if you want an empty string to replace previous values, just set all v-variables to "" after they're printed `... print v1","v2","v3; v1=v2=v3=""}...` also edited the answer.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the trailing comma for missing check_interval : `... /check_interval/{v3=","$2} /}/{print v1","v2""v3; v1=v2=v3=""} ...`

Comment: amazing! reassigning empty values before the next loop..quite clever! :D thanks !